# How to use Master Data Services data then? The MDS lifecycle

Tags: sql, sql-server, master-data-services, master-data-management, mds

So I know that we need to create Master Data Services db to make data clean, right, consistent, etc. We can import some data there, then process it.. and then? We should then export it to another db, is it so? So MDS is like a set of tools to clean and make your data right, and it is for only one use, right? I mean: we have our data -> we load it in MDS db with SSIS -> we process it, apply business rules, etc. -> we export it to our SQL Server db with SSIS -> then we can use it as we like.

Am I right?

I want to understand how MDS are using in practice, where data is going after MDS processes and where from data is got.

Thanks and sorry if it is dump question.

Answer (score -1):

Using Master Data Services in conjunction with Data Quality Services and Integration Services, enables you to clean & normalize a data set, store it as your master (trusted) set of data, and enable others in your organization to view/share this master/trusted data set.

You may find this tutorial, last updated for SQL Server 2014, helpful in better understanding how to use these three technologies together -- [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819782(v=sql.120).aspx](http://Using%20Master%20Data%20Services%20in%20conjunction%20with%20Data%20Quality%20Services%20and%20Integration%20Services,%20enables%20you%20to%20clean%20&%20normalize%20a%20data%20set,%20store%20it%20as%20your%20master%20(trusted)%20set%20of%20data,%20and%20enable%20others%20in%20your%20organization%20to%20view/share%20this%20master/trusted%20data%20set.%20You%20may%20find%20this%20tutorial,%20last%20updated%20for%20SQL%20Server%202014,%20helpful%20in%20better%20understanding%20how%20to%20use%20these%20three%20technologies%20together%20--%20https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819782(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Hi, the link is not accessible anymore, can you explain in detail? -thanks